# How can I abort/rollback a HBase pending procedures?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, procedure

I have a list of pending HBase procedures. I want to rollback all of it. How can I do that? An output of list_procedure command -

```
PID Name State Submitted Last_Update Parameters

7 org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.procedure.CreateTableProcedure WAITING 2019-02-27 20:16:51 +0530 2019-02-27 20:16:51 +0530 [{"state"=>[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}, {"userInfo"=>{"effectiveUser"=>"hadoop"}, "tableSchema"=>{"tableName"=>{"namespace"=>"ZGVmYXVsdA==", "qualifier"=>"dXNlcmF0dHJpYnV0ZXM="}, "attributes"=>[{"first"=>"SVNfTUVUQQ==", "second"=>"ZmFsc2U="}], "columnFamilies"=>[{"name"=>"Y2Y=", "attributes"=>[{"first"=>"VkVSU0lPTlM=", "second"=>"MQ=="}, {"first"=>"RVZJQ1RfQkxPQ0tTX09OX0NMT1NF", "second"=>"ZmFsc2U="}, {"first"=>"TkVXX1ZFUlNJT05fQkVIQVZJT1I=", "second"=>"ZmFsc2U="}, {"first"=>"S0VFUF9ERUxFVEVEX0NFTExT", "second"=>"RkFMU0U="}, {"first"=>"Q0FDSEVfREFUQV9PTl9XUklURQ==", "second"=>"ZmFsc2U="}, {"first"=>"REFUQV9CTE9DS19FTkNPRElORw==", "second"=>"Tk9ORQ=="}, {"first"=>"VFRM", "second"=>"MjE0NzQ4MzY0Nw=="}, {"first"=>"TUlOX1ZFUlNJT05T", "second"=>"MA=="}, {"first"=>"UkVQTElDQVRJT05fU0NPUEU=", "second"=>"MA=="}, {"first"=>"QkxPT01GSUxURVI=", "second"=>"Uk9X"}, {"first"=>"Q0FDSEVfSU5ERVhfT05fV1JJVEU=", "second"=>"ZmFsc2U="}, {"first"=>"SU5fTUVNT1JZ", "second"=>"ZmFsc2U="}, {"first"=>"Q0FDSEVfQkxPT01TX09OX1dSSVRF", "second"=>"ZmFsc2U="}, {"first"=>"UFJFRkVUQ0hfQkxPQ0tTX09OX09QRU4=", "second"=>"ZmFsc2U="}, {"first"=>"Q09NUFJFU1NJT04=", "second"=>"U05BUFBZ"}, {"first"=>"QkxPQ0tDQUNIRQ==", "second"=>"dHJ1ZQ=="}, {"first"=>"QkxPQ0tTSVpF", "second"=>"NjU1MzY="}]}]}, "regionInfo"=>[{"regionId"=>"1551278811285", "tableName"=>{"namespace"=>"ZGVmYXVsdA==", "qualifier"=>"dXNlcmF0dHJpYnV0ZXM="}, "startKey"=>"", "endKey"=>"", "offline"=>false, "split"=>false, "replicaId"=>0}]}]
8 org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.assignment.AssignProcedure WAITING_TIMEOUT 2019-02-27 20:16:51 +0530 2019-02-28 17:10:58 +0530 [{"transitionState"=>"REGION_TRANSITION_QUEUE", "regionInfo"=>{"regionId"=>"1551278811285", "tableName"=>{"namespace"=>"ZGVmYXVsdA==", "qualifier"=>"dXNlcmF0dHJpYnV0ZXM="}, "startKey"=>"", "endKey"=>"", "offline"=>false, "split"=>false, "replicaId"=>0}, "forceNewPlan"=>true, "attempt"=>18}]
9 org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.procedure.EnableTableProcedure RUNNABLE 2019-02-27 20:29:41 +0530 2019-02-27 20:29:41 +0530 [{}, {"userInfo"=>{"effectiveUser"=>"hadoop"}, "tableName"=>{"namespace"=>"ZGVmYXVsdA==", "qualifier"=>"dXNlcmF0dHJpYnV0ZXM="}, "skipTableStateCheck"=>false}]
10 org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.procedure.EnableTa
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can't rollback procedure manually. HBase will rollback it in case of errors.
Procedure abort is also not available anymore, please see [HBASE-21223](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-21223).
If your procedures cannot be finished because it stucked(you can see special log messages in HBase master logs), I think you should report it to HBase developers.